# Simple HTML DOM Parser - Skip certain element

Tags: php, web-scraping

I am using the Simple HTML DOM Parser and I want to completely ignore the contents of the "nested" element and get the contents of the proceeding "pre" element.

```
<div id=parent>

<div class="nested">
<pre>Text that I want ignored</pre>
</div>

<pre>
This is the text I want to access
</pre>
</div>
```

I don't have control of the HTML source, and the owner has recently added the "nested" element.  Before I accessed the content I needed by doing so:

```
$page_contents = file_get_html($url);    
$div_content = $page_contents->find('div[id=parent]pre', 0)->innertext;
```

But obviously the new nested element has broken my method.

I can't seem to find any official documentation regarding this kind of scenario.

Comment: Alright, updated my answer where I could.

Comment: Why don't you code a function that iterates among the children of the div with id "parent" and ignore the children that aren't pre? Iterating though these children will bypass "Text that I want to ignore" cause it isn't a child of the div id parent, although their are indirectly related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not tested but try this

```
$div_content = $page_contents->find('div[id=parent][class!=nested]pre', 0)->innertext;
```

or

```
$div_content = $page_contents->find('div[id=parent class!=nested]pre', 0)->innertext;
```

or maybe even just this I think this is really the one but again I have not tested

```
$div_content = $page_contents->find('div[class!=nested]pre', 1)->innertext;
```

still don't know if this will work but try this

```
$div_content = $page_contents->find('div[class!=nested pre]', 0)->innertext;
```

or

```
$div_content = $page_contents->find('div[class!=nested pre]', 0)->plaintext;
```

Comment: Hmm, both the first and third return "Text that I want ignored", meanwhile the 2nd one returns an error.

Comment: @Nate Shoffner if you change the 0 to 1 do you get the right thing ?

Comment: I was just looking in the documentation to see what that parameter was for.  And yes it works.  This is what the documentation says:  "Find (N)th anchor, returns element object or null if not found (zero based)"

Comment: The 3rd snippet is the one that worked when changing the 2nd parameter to 1.  If you update the snippet, I'll accept your answer. :)

Comment: @nate-shoffner edited answer add some other things to try too

Answer (score 0):

`find('div[id=parent] pre')` finds all `pre` tags in specified `div` and doesnt care if one of them is enclosed in another `div`, so heres a few suggestions:

if you know exactly which `pre` you want to get, just specify the number counting from zero, in your case:

```
$div_content = $page_contents->find('div[id=parent] pre', 1)->innertext;
```

in case you dont know how many `pre` are there, or dont know the order, you could just remove the one you dont want and then do the previous line, but this time specifying number 0:

```
$page_contents->find('div[id=parent] div[id=nested] pre', 0)->outertext = '';
$div_content = $page_contents->find('div[id=parent] pre', 0)->innertext;
```

and in case you dont want to change `$page_contents`, just assign your parent `div` to a temporary variable, and do like above:

```
$temp = $page_contents->find('div[id=parent]', 0);
$temp->find('div[id=nested] pre', 0)->outertext='';
$div_content = $temp->find('pre', 0)->innertext;
```

ofcourse there are a lot of other ways to do this, should read the manual http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm though it mentions just the main features, a lot more is under the hood