# Simple HTML DOM Parser - Get all plaintex rather than text of certain element

Tags: php, parsing, dom, html-parsing, web-scraping

I tried all the solutions posted on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595746/simple-html-dom-parser-skip-certain-element). Although it is similar to my question, it's solutions aren't working for me.

I am trying to get the plain text that is outside of `<b>` and it should be inside the `<div id="maindiv>`.

```
<div id=maindiv>
     <b>I don't want this text</b>
     I want this text
</div>
```

**$part** is the object that contains `<div id="maindiv">`.
Now I tried this:

```
$part->find('!b')->innertext;
```

The code above is not working. When I tried this

`$part->plaintext;`

it returned all of the plain text like this

```
I don't want this text I want this text
```

I read the official documentation, but I didn't find anything to resolve this:

Answer (score 0):

Query:

```
$selector->query('//div[@id="maindiv"]/text()[2]')
```

Explanation:

```
//               - selects nodes regardless of their position in tree

div              - selects elements which node name is 'div'

[@id="maindiv"]  - selects only those divs having the attribute id="maindiv"

/                - sets focus to the div element

text()           - selects only text elements

[2]              - selects the second text element (the first is whitespace)

                   Note! The actual position of the text element may depend on
                   your preserveWhitespace setting.

                   Manual: http://www.php.net/manual/de/class.domdocument.php#domdocument.props.preservewhitespace
```

Example:

```
$html = <<<EOF
<div id="maindiv">
     <b>I dont want this text</b>
     I want this text
</div>
EOF;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$selector = new DOMXpath($doc);   

$node = $selector->query('//div[@id="maindiv"]/text()[2]')->item(0);
echo trim($node->nodeValue); // I want this text
```

Comment: than you for your quick reply, Could you please explain it for me.

Answer (score 0):

remove the `<b>` first:

```
$part->find('b', 0)->outertext = '';
echo $part->innertext; // I want this text
```